# autofill container using keyboard digits

Tags: flutter

I am continuously trying to fill container by pressing keyboard digits I  want to autofill that circular shape container to autofill container is not working. What should I do? Please tell me.

[image]

Comment: Can you share code snippets?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

u can specify two more parameter one for `focusNode` of current textfield & another one for focus u want to change . you can have textField with icon where you can show the ui as per your screenshot . e.g.

```
textField(
    text: '1stelement', 
    focusNode: // your focus node, 
    nextFocusNode: // your next field focus node
),
```

now u can use :

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
```